# Function taking a variable list of arguments and converting them to a series of bytes?

Tags: c++

I want to create a function, say `pack()`, that takes a variable list of arguments and converts them to a series of bytes, e.g., `std::vector`.

Given `char c = 0x10, int x = 4, char *s = "AAA"`, then `pack()`, should behave like:

`pack(c, x, s) = 0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41`.

(here I assume little-endian byte ordering)

How would I program such function?

I've been thinking about C's `va_list` or C++'s template mechanisms, but I've trouble implementing this.

What is the "best" way of programming such function? Any code snippets demonstrating a suitable technique?

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that describes variadic templates, and start reading. This is one of the most complicated parts of C++, that cannot be fully addressed in one or two paragraphs in a stackoverflow.com answer. The short answer is: learn how to use variadic templates.

Comment: But given such template, how would I get the type of the arguments such that I can extract the bytes using, e.g., a `char *` pointer?

Comment: You can implement a streaming operator and overload it.

Comment: This should be explained in the aforementioned chapter in your C++, that should have plenty of examples of implementing recursive template functions that collect their arguments into a container, of some kind.

Comment: Note that variadic templates appeared in C++11 only, so the book should be fairly modern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share my solution. Its advantage over the previously proposed once is that it work for all types: fundamental types, static arrays, custom objects, containers (vector, list, string...), C-strings (both literal and dynamically allocated).

If you want to limit those types (say, not to allow packing pointers) you can always add more SFINAE :) Or just a `static_assert`...

```
// byte_pack.h

#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// a small trait to check if it is possible to iterate over T
template<typename T, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_iterable = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_iterable<T, decltype(
        std::begin(std::declval<T&>()) != std::end(std::declval<T&>()), void())> = true;

typedef std::vector<std::uint8_t> byte_pack; // vector of bytes itself

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<(!is_iterable<T>)>* = nullptr>
void pack(byte_pack& bytes, const T& value)  // for not iteratable values (int, double, custom objects, etc.)
{
    typedef const std::uint8_t byte_array[sizeof value];
    for(auto& byte : reinterpret_cast<byte_array&>(value)) {
        bytes.push_back(byte);
    }
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_iterable<T>>* = nullptr>
void pack(byte_pack& bytes, const T& values) // for iteratable values (string, vector, etc.)
{
    for(const auto& value : values) {
        pack(bytes, value);
    }
}

template<>
inline void pack(byte_pack& bytes, const char* const & c_str) // for C-strings
{
    for(auto i = 0; c_str[i]; ++i) {
        bytes.push_back(c_str[i]);
    }
}

template<>
inline void pack(byte_pack& bytes, char* const & c_str) { // for C-strings
    pack(bytes, static_cast<const char*>(c_str));
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void pack(byte_pack& bytes, const T (&values) [N])  // for static arrays
{
    for(auto i = 0u; i < N; ++i) {
        pack(bytes, values[i]);
    }
}

// finally a variadic overload
template<typename... Args>
byte_pack pack(const Args&... args)
{
    byte_pack bytes;
    int dummy[] = { 0, (pack(bytes, args), 0) ... };
    return bytes;
}
```

---

***Tests:***

```
#include "byte_pack.h"

void cout_bytes(const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& bytes)
{
    for(unsigned byte : bytes) {
        std::cout << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex
                   << byte << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // your example
    char c = 0x10; int x = 4; const char* s = "AAA";
    cout_bytes(pack(c, x, s));

    // static arrays and iterateble objects
    char                            matrix1[2][2] = { {0x01, 0x01},  {0xff, 0xff} };
    std::vector<std::vector<char>>  matrix2       = { {(char) 0x01, (char) 0x01},  {(char) 0xff, (char) 0xff} };
    cout_bytes(pack(matrix1, matrix2));

    // strings
    char*       str2 = new char[4] { "AAA" };
    std::string str1 = "AAA";
    cout_bytes(pack(str1, str2));

    // custom objects (remember about alignment!)
    struct { char a = 0x01;     short b = 0xff; }   object1;
    struct { short a = 0x01ff;  char b = 0x01; }    object2;
    cout_bytes(pack(object1, object2));

    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

```
0x10 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x41 0x41 0x41
0x01 0x01 0xff 0xff 0x01 0x01 0xff 0xff
0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41
0x01 0x00 0xff 0x00 0xff 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

Comment: Does the "&" in `char* const & c_str` mean a reference?

Comment: Ah) because my primary template takes  `const T& value`. So if I write just `char*` it is an invalid specialization (can be only an overload). But if I make it an overload, overload priority starts to play and on passing an array of chars `chars[]`, this overload gets called. However, it is intended for c-strings only, so I will get a wrong result.

Comment: If you are not going to pass any heavy, non-itrateble objects, than you can just replace `const T& value` with `T value` and then `char*` and `const char*` (without that weird `const &`) will work just fine.

Comment: Ahh thanks, - what if I need to use the templates in several source files? Will I need to inline the implementations then? I need to define the templates in the same header as the declarations, right?

Comment: Now, you can just put all this code in a separate header and it can be used as a header-only implementation. (Don't forget about include guards or `#pragma once`)

Comment: Why are only some of the template definitions inline? Are there alternatives to inline?

Comment: Hmm, what is wrong with `inline`? All unspecialized templates already may get inlined by default. However,  I put inline near full specializations because otherwise I will have to move them to a separate cpp file while including this header in more that one place (one definition rule). Here are some useful links: [inline templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates), [inline full template specializations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667098/inline-template-function).

Comment: When the compiler use unspecialized templates to create functions "under the hood", i.e., the template is invoked from some .cpp file -- does the compiler then name the template-derived (created) functions so that multiple definitions are avoided? Or say a template, `pack()`, is invoked with the same types of parameter from two .cpp files - will this result in a multiple definition error, or is the compiler smart enough to make either one definition or two definitions with different names?

Comment: @Shuzheng, yes, of course! that is the basics of templates usage. [Read this, please.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200752/c-header-only-template-library). Put all templates in a header is standard practice. Compiler will figure everything out.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
void pack_in_vector(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& v, char c)
{
    v.push_back(c);
}

void pack_in_vector(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& v, int n)
{
    v.push_back(n & 0xFF);
    v.push_back((n >> 8) & 0xFF);
    v.push_back((n >> 16) & 0xFF);
    v.push_back((n >> 24) & 0xFF);
}

void pack_in_vector(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& v, const std::string& s)
{
    for (c : s) {
        v.push_back(c);    
    }
}

template <typename ... Ts>
std::vector<std::uint8_t> pack(const Ts&... args)
{
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes;
    (pack_in_vector(bytes, args), ...); // Folding expression requires C++17
    return bytes;
}
```

For C++11, you have to modify last function to:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::vector<std::uint8_t> pack(const Ts&... args)
{
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes;

    int dummy[] = {0, (pack_in_vector(bytes, args), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like this. Is there some way of modifying it, so that it compiles with C++11?

Comment: For extra points, you could do `bytes.reserve((sizeof(args) + ...));`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Which is not necessary accurate: `sizeof(std::string)`

Comment: @jarod42 it doesn't have to be perfect.  In addition, a `byteof` function could be written that would make it perfect.  Me, I'd solve this problem with a byte-sink pattern, then write the reserve and push back in terms of a byte-sink.  As a bonus, recursive byte-sinking of containers could fall out.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F>
void range_to_bytes( F&& f, char const* begin, char const* end ){
  for(auto*it=begin; it != end; ++it)
    f(*it);
}
template<class F>
void to_bytes( F&& f, char c ){
  range_to_bytes(f, &c, &c+1);
}
template<class F>
void to_bytes( F&& f, int i ){
  range_to_bytes(f, (const char*)(&i), (const char*)(&i+1));
}
template<class F>
void to_bytes( F&& f, char const* str ){
  range_to_bytes(f, str, str+strlen(str));
}
template<class F, class...Ts>
void to_bytes( F&& f, Ts const&... ts ){
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void(
    to_bytes(f, ts)
  ),0)...}
}
template<class...Ts>
std::vector<char> to_vector_bytes( Ts const&... ts ){
  std::size_t count = 0;
  to_bytes([&](char){++count;}, ts...);
  std::vector<char> r;
  r.reserve(count);
  to_bytes([&](char c){r.push_back(c);}, ts...);
  return r;
}
```