# How can I combine return type deduction, template instantiation with header files?

Tags: c++, templates, inline, header-files, return-type-deduction

I would like to combine return type deduction and explicit template instantiation (e.g. `f<int>` instead of `template<typename T> f<T>`). The example below shows how this can be done in **one file** [play with code](https://godbolt.org/z/Ja3oLs).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Enum { String, Int };

template <Enum E>
auto f();

template <>
auto f<Enum::String> () {
   return "string";
}

template <>
auto f<Enum::Int> () {
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    const Enum e = Enum::String;
    auto a = f<e>();
    const Enum g = Enum::Int;
    auto b = f<g>();

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:** How can I combine return type deduction, template instantiation with header files?

What I would like:

```
// f.hpp
template<Enum E> auto f();
```

```
// f.cpp
f<Enum::Int> f() { // ...
```

```
// other_file.cpp
#include "f.hpp"
auto a = f<Enum::Int>();
```

**Error:** `function 'f<Enum::Int>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined`.

**Ideas:**

IMO the error makes sense since the function instantiation is not in the header and was thus not included in `other_file.cpp`.

I am unable to write the instantiations in the `f.hpp` since they are instantiations (obviously).

I thought about using `inline`, but that did not help (why?).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought about using inline, but that did not help (why?).

regarding the inline keyword here:

```
// f.hpp
template<Enum E> auto f();
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

> There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: class type, enumeration type, inline function, inline variable (since C++17), templated entity (template or member of template, but not full template specialization)

in short, you dont need inline for templates (unless its a full specialization)

in this case:

```
// f.cpp
f<Enum::Int> f() { // ...
```

you would need the inline keyword if this was in a header file. For ODR purposes this full specialization is basically treated as a function definition. Although since this definition is only in one cpp file, there is only one definition anyway so the inline keyword doesn't help.

for more info on inline with templates see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17667265/11429904

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the 2 definitions you provide for `f` are called *explicit specializations*. You cannot define them in a dedicated implementation file because the compiler must know their return type.

In this situation a possible work around, if you want to use deduced return type, is to pack the specialization definition within the primary template definition using a constexpr if statement, and then use *explicit template instantiation*:

Inside `f.hpp`:

```
enum Enum { String, Int };

template <Enum E>
auto f(){
    if constexpr (E==String)
       return "string";
    else
       return 2;
}

extern template
auto f<Enum::String> ();

extern template
auto f<Enum::Int> ();
```

Inside `f.cpp`:

```
#include "f.hpp"
template
auto f<Enum::String> ();

template
auto f<Enum::Int> ();
```

Comment: Nice! I tried the `constexpr if` on its own. I was not aware that I have to combine it with the explicit specializations. Also I am using C++ 17. Extern is reserved but has no meaning there, correct?

Comment: Not have to. Take care of the terms "explicit specialization" and "explicit instantiation". Those two terms does not mean the same thing. In your question you do an "explicit specialization": you provide a definition for a specific template argument. A template instantiation is when you ask the compiler to use the generic definition to produce an instance for given template arguments. The `extern` is required. It means that what followes is a declaration. Without the extern, the explicit instantiation is a definition.