# #define or typed function?

Tags: c++, function, optimization

Not sure which is better (faster) about these two way:

```
// first
#define BOUNDED(x,lo,hi) ((x) < (lo) ? (lo) : (x) > (hi) ? (hi) : (x))

// second
double Bounded(double x, double lo, double hi) {
    return fmax(fmin(x, hi), lo);
};
```

In both I'll use them with `double`. Does it depends by the compiler?

Comment: In the second one, you have a total of 3 function-calls. If they are not all inlined, then it will probably be slower than the first one.

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Comment: How about this: Focus on writing correct and maintainable code and choosing the right data structures and algorithms and let the compiler optimize things. Then, if you need more performance still, use a profiler and chip away at the identified hotspots and forget this business about macros vs functions and which one is faster.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Absolutely. I'd rather pay for a 10% increase in my compute farm than have all these macros flying around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule of thumb in C++ is to *avoid macros whenever possible*.

For example, your macro will suffer from repeated evaluation of arguments if I pass something like `BOUNDED(x++, low++, hi++)`.

If you want to retain the generic nature of the macro, then why not write

```
template<typename Y>
inline Y Bounded(Y x, Y lo, Y hi)
{
    return x < lo ? lo : x > hi ? hi : x;
}
```

I can't see this being slower than the macro approach. Note that the compiler may ignore `inline` as it sees fit. Profile the performance to be sure. You could consider passing `const Y& x` etc. for large types, but this will probably wind up *slower* for the `Y` = `double` case.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but the question asks which one is **faster**, not which one is more suitable for the conventions of the C++ language.

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes I just noticed I didn't really answer that. Have done so now.

Comment: Don't you think that the function-call has any runtime impact? (unless inlined, and even so, if I remember correctly, it is just a recommendation for the compiler, so there's no guarantee to avoid the function-call).

Comment: @barakmanos, Compilers are quite good at figuring out when to inline and when not to. On average they produce better running code than the "optimizing" developer who thinks they know when to inline.

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes, adding `inline` is probably wise, although these days compilers tend to be better than their advisors, if you get my meaning.

Comment: @Bathsheba, but not required. All function templates are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates

Comment: @Bathsheba, explicit instantiation notwithstanding, there is no point in marking a template as inline. A good lecture on the subject from this years cppcon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwrXHznaYLA

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'd go one step further and dare suggest there's no point in making *any* function `inline`.

Comment: @Bathsheba,  you'd be wrong :) See the lecture. the `inline` keyword has a very specific meaning as a linker directive. A regular function in a header (not a template) will produce a "multiple definition" error, unless it is marked with the `inline` keyword. Of course, one can ask *why* have a function definition in a header, but that's an entirely different matter. :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes that was a silly thing to say. I'll leave it up since my removing it will invalidate your helpful comment.

Comment: If they're always of `double` type, then I believe `long_running_function()` instead of `low++` would be closer to a possible use case to illustrate the problem with the macro.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I would choose function and made it templatized `constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T Bounded(T x, T lo, T hi)
{
    return x < lo ? lo : x > hi ? hi : x;
}
```

That way you have generic approach (as with macro) but with two advantages:

1. You can use concepts (once they enter standard :) ) to constrain types passed into template.
2. It will be evaluated at compile time if you pass `constexpr` arguments.

As for your exact question:

Modern compilers are good at optimizing. Very good in fact. I suspect that because of those optimizations both versions will take similar time to execute. But without profiling on your build configuration it's just wild guess.

Comment: Well, you can constrain it nowadays anyway. All it takes is one `enable_if<is_arithmetic<...>>`

Comment: Sure, concepts just cleaner and more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add this for completeness. Once c++17 comes along, you can just use [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)

```
template<class T>
constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi );
template<class T, class Compare>
constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi, Compare comp );
```

> 1. If v compares less than hi, returns the larger of v and lo,
>      otherwise returns the smaller of v and hi. Uses operator< to compare
>      the values.
> 2. Same as (1), but uses comp to compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that you should to trust c++ compiler and use function instead macro, because it can perform some optimizations like inlining (which will do all necessary work for you). Moreover, usage of macro in c++ is bad practise, which can lead to errors