# What's the right way to implement integer division-rounding-up?

Tags: c++, integer-division, idioms, rounding

It's very common to need to divide integers but get the result rounded up rather than down. For a while now, I've been using the following function for that mini-idiom:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
constexpr inline S div_rounding_up(const S& dividend, const T& divisor) 
{
    return (dividend + divisor - 1) / divisor;
}
```

This has (at least) the following deficiences, or what may be seen as deficiencies:

- While it works "as promised" with negative operands - it's called `div_rounding_up` - it would probably make more sense to have this kind of function round away-from-zero, since `x / y` for negative `x` and positive `y` rounds towards zero. In other words, maybe what I should be implementing is `div_rounding_away_from_zero`, which would be commutative with inversion: Letting `auto f = [&y](const S& x) { return div_rounding_away_from_zero(x,y); }` we would have `f(-x) == -f(x)`.
- Overflow near the end of the domain of `S`.
- Possibly weird behavior when `sizeof(S) > sizeof(T)`.
- long function name...

While you can easily think of ways of addressing each of these, they then result in other possible deficiencies, like conditionals in the code, or a reliance on calculating the modulus which may be expensive.

So is there a "right way" to implement this? By "right" I mean semantically pleasing, efficient, avoiding as many of the deficiencies above, and hopefully widely-used.

**Notes:**

- If you think the function should be strictly constained to only work with non-negative arguments, say so. That would be a bit problematic IMHO since we don't want to constrain the types to be unsigned, and we don't want to check the operands' signs. That seems like something I would use a contact for - and C++ doesn't have them yet.
- Is using `std::div` and variants a good idea here?
- Performance is more important than readability. At worst one can add a comment.
- Code should not be single-architecture-specific (but if you want to ifdef-else for different architectures then be my guest).
- Code should not assume a specific compiler.

Comment: There is no need to sum dividend and divisor: distribute the division across that sum.

Comment: @Bathsheba If I understood you well, would your suggesstion work for integer division?

Comment: For the different types problem perhaps you could use `T` for both types and require the caller to pass the same type

Comment: @A.s.h. Yes it would, since you'd be bringing out an integer from the expression.

Comment: @M.M: I didn't say that. It's just that it's extremely rare for me to want/have to do this for negative operands.

Comment: @M.M: Regarding `inline` for templated functions - I believe you're [mistaken](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10536588/1593077).

Comment: @Bathsheba: Are you suggesting I perform two divisions?

Comment: @M.M: Let me know if my edits are satisfactory in this respect.

Comment: @einpoklum `it rounds up, instead of rounding away-from-zero - which is what I would expect for negative numbers (since x / y for negative x and positive y rounds towards zero).` Why would you expect a function called "round up" to not round up, but away from zero?

Comment: @M.M: How about now?

Comment: @user2079303: See edit.

Comment: I don't see what's so bad about a simple conditional.Do a normal division, do a multiplication to see if `result*divisor == dividend`, if not so, add 1 (or -1 if negative), return final value.

Comment: No I'm not suggesting that. One of the terms will be 1. That, elegantly, reduces he possibility of overflow.

Comment: @coyotte508: And introduce a highly unpredictable branch? I don't think so...

Comment: @Bathsheba: I'm not quite following... how about making your suggestin an answer and being more explicit?

Comment: Cuz I'm on a plane, innit. Safety demo. There must be a duplicate for this part of the question: this is a well-known problem.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Original, and valid, excuse I suppose. Anyway, I would also think there must be a dupe for this, and yet - I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

> Possibly weird behavior when `sizeof(S) > sizeof(T)`.

It would probably be better to use a single type argument, and let the user deal with the conversion that they want. This is the approach used by the standard library math functions.

> Overflow near the end of the domain of S.

A remainder based rounding does not have this problem.

> reliance on calculating the modulus which may be expensive.

You are already calculating a division, which is expensive. On x86 at least, the division instruction stores the remainder in a register, and a decent implementation of `std::div` will use it. A modern compiler will even be able to optimize explicit use of division and remainder operation as well.

> Is using `std::div` and variants a good idea here?

Sure.

> If you think the function should be strictly constained to only work with non-negative arguments, say so.

I think you should at least require that arguments must have the same sign. The direction of rounding of both division and remainder operator (also by extension `std::div` since C++11) is implementation defined. With this requirement, there is no difference between rounding away from zero, and rounding up, since no supported result is negative.

```
template <typename T> // single type argument
constexpr T           // constexpr implies inline
div_round_up
(const T& dividend, const T& divisor) 
{
    // no overflows, only 1 expensive operation
    std::div_t dv = std::div(dividend, divisor);
    return dv.quot + (!!dv.rem);
}
```