# uint64_t: Division with rounding

Tags: c, gcc, rounding, division, integer-division

I'm trying to create a code which divides a `uint64_t` by another `uint64_t` plus it applies rounding to the result. The code should be as fast as possible and work for all inputs (e.g. I would prefer it to now have and conditionals).

My current solution looks like this:

```
static inline uint64_t divide_with_rounding(uint64_t n, uint64_t d)
{
    uint64_t a = n / d;
    uint64_t r = n % d;
    return a + (r >= d - (d / 2));
}
```

gcc optimizes the division+modulo quite nicely and as well the `/ 2`. But I wonder if there's a shorter and nicer solution.

E.g. something like this:

```
static inline uint64_t divide_with_rounding(uint64_t n, uint64_t d)
{
    return (n + d / 2) / d;
}
```

However that one has the disadvantage that `divide_with_rounding(UINT64_MAX, 1000)` produces 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding integer division (instead of truncating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/rounding-integer-division-instead-of-truncating)

Comment: round to nearest: `(n + d/2)/d`, to +inf: `(n + d - 1)/d`. duplicates: [What's the right way to implement integer division-rounding-up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41870852/995714), [Divide integers with floor, ceil and outwards rounding modes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63436490/995714), [signed integer division with rounding in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60009772/995714), [Fast ceiling of an integer division in C / C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745074/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is [round(x/d) = ⌊(x + d/2)/d⌋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Rounding) mathematically. From the [property of floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences) ⌊x + n⌋ = ⌊x⌋ + n we can prove that in case d is even the result is

[image: \left\lfloor \frac{n + \left\lfloor \frac{d}{2}\right\rfloor }{d} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n - \frac{d}{2} + d}{d} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n - \frac{d}{2}}{d} + 1 \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n - \frac{d}{2}}{d} \right\rfloor + 1]

In case d is odd we can replace d = 2k + 1 and prove that the result is the same. Therefore you can just use

```
if (n >= d/2)
    return (n - d/2)/d + 1;
else
    return (n + d/2)/d;
```

This will avoid the situation where `n + d/2` overflows

However in case `d` is not a compile-time constant then it might be faster to do a 128-by-64-bit division if the branch misprediction cost is high. In MSVC you can do like this

```
uint64_t nH = 0, nL = n, rem = 0;
nL += d/2;
nH += nL < n;                        // { nH, nL } += d/2
return _udiv128(nH, nL, d, &rem);    // { nH, nL } / d
```

and in compilers with `__int128` type like GCC, ICC, Clang... just use it directly

```
__int128 N = n;
N += d/2;
return N/d;
```