# How to avoid redefinition of template<class T> error when including headers

Tags: c++, templates

I have created my first template class, from which both class A and class B descend.  Now, in C.h i include both A.h and B.h

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308216/why-am-i-getting-redefinition-of-templateclass-t-if-i-use-inline-function-in) you can only use the same template once per translation unit.  I understand that - but how do I prevent the error above?  Since A and B use the same template in their class definition lines, they will both be pulled into the same C.h file.  I don't see how I can split this into multiple files.

Do I need to put an include guard in the template .h file?  (But then how will the second usage of the template know the T in class  is different?

Comment: please post an [mcve] . You didn't even say what the error was.  You put a header/include guard on *EVERY* header file.

Comment: Yes, you need an include guard. Your parenthetical note at the end suggests that you have some misunderstanding of what templates are, but I can't figure out what. :-/

Comment: The error is in the title of this question.

Comment: @ruakh - yes include guard worked, but I'm confused.  Does that mean the template only needs to be included once, and each time it is used the compiler substitutes the T for that specific usage?

Comment: @TSG Without include guards, what would happen if you did this: `#include "header.h"`  followed by another `#include "header.h"`?   See any potential issues with that?  If you do, then that's why include guards are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean the template only needs to be included once, and each time it is used the compiler substitutes the T for that specific usage?

Yes, that's the whole point of a class template; you just define it once (plus any specializations), and the compiler generates a separate class for each distinct *instantiation* of the template.

For example, this:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Foo {
};
```

allows you to then write `Foo<int>`, `Foo<long>`, `Foo<std::string>`, `Foo<Foo<int> *>`, etc., etc., and the compiler will generate the requisite class for each.