# Inlining Template Specialization

Tags: c++, inline, template-specialization, one-definition-rule, template-function

If I have a header foo.h which I include all over my project, it seems to work fine when all it contains is:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T param) {
    cout << param << endl;
}
```

But I get one definition rule (ODR) errors when I add a specalization to foo.h:

```
template<>
void foo(const bool param) {
    cout << param << endl;
}
```

Obviously I can solve this by `inline`'ing the specialization. My question is, why do I need to? If the template doesn't violate ODR, why does a specialization?

Comment: A specialisation of a template function is a definition, if the body is defined.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I looked at that one... it doesn't address specialization. I was really just hoping for something official saying I had to `inline`. Looks like [StoryTeller has got me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51987559/2642059).

Comment: @JonathanMee It doesn't?  What about in the middle of the answer under *tpl.h (taken from Explicit Specialization):* that has the exact same code block?

Comment: @NathanOliver Heh... well look at that. I only looked at the question :/ I wouldn't mind duping this. Since it's well answered over there. What do you think?

Comment: BTW, overloading is generally better than specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you explain further? Why is it generally better?

Comment: @JonathanMee - Her's an SO post chewing it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading

Comment: @Jarod42 I was looking into this further and found this excellent write up, so I thought I'd share it here: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An explicit specialization is not implicitly inline. It must be explicitly made inline.

> [**[temp.expl.spec]/12**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#12)
>
> An explicit specialization of a function or variable template is
>   inline only if it is declared with the inline specifier or defined as
>   deleted, and independently of whether its function or variable
>   template is inline. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void f(T) { /* ... */ }
> template<class T> inline T g(T) { /* ... */ }
>
> template<> inline void f<>(int) { /* ... */ }   // OK: inline
> template<> int g<>(int) { /* ... */ }           // OK: not inline
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So you have to do it, because the standard says you have to do it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why templates are exempt from ODR is simply that there is no other choice.

A template is not a "tangible end-product" from compiler's perspective.  The implementation of templates must be carried around so that it can be expanded into compilable code when used.  As a result, it must reside in a header file, and duplicate definitions from different compilation units are consequent and unavoidable.  Since it is unavoidable, the standard makes a compromise to exempt them from ODR.

A function is an end-product that can be readily compiled into target code, so compilers hate to see potentially conflicting definitions, even if it is entirely possible to compare the codes and proceed if the codes are identical.  However, the compilers decide they are way too lazy to do such extra check, and hence the standard banned multiple definitions.

Now, an *explicit/full* specialization of a template function is *de facto* a function, not a template - as all the missing pieces have been filled and there is no need to carry the definition of the specialized function around anymore.  In contrast, a *partial* specialization is *de facto* a template, as its implementation still needs to be carried around during compilation.  Therefore, partial template specializations enjoy the exempt inherited from templates, whereas explicit/full specializations don't.

Comment: template are not exempt of ODR, token should be identical, resulting instantiation should "behave" identically (visible function for ADL, ...). It just doesn't require `inline` keyword.