# Effect of inline keyword on class member template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, inline

I've read about inlining template function specalizations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates)

Apart from requiring `inline` keyword for instantation in a header which is logical, I can't find an answer whether it makes any difference to mark non specialized function templates as `inline` in a header? be it member functions or just normal functions.

Please save from explaining how compiler knows better than programmer, the question is: does `inline` keyword makes any sense for "unpacked" templates in a header?

are non specialized templates always inline since they are in a header? for bellow example pseudo code if we suppose `Foo::bar` method can be either very lengthy or very short, does omitting `inline` keyword or adding `inline` keyword has any effect on acctual chance of inlining or not inlining expanded function by the compiler?

Here is an example for member function templates which reflects my code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename Type>
    static Type bar();
};
```

**Example non inline definition:**

```
template<typename Type>
Type Foo::bar()
{
    return Type();
}
```

**Example inline definition:**

```
template<typename Type>
inline Type Foo::bar()
{
    return Type();
}
```

Is this `inline` keyword above always useless, or it makes sense only if the function can be inlined by the compiler? are templates always inline in a header?

Comment: `inline` is implied in the first block. I'm trying to find a reference to it in the standard.

Comment: I'm looking forward for such confirmation, that would answer everthing.

Comment: I'm not finding it. Perhaps someone with better knowledge of the standard can.

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` keyword is used to bypass the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), not for indicating [*inline substitution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) of the function call. Note that the compiler still needs the function definition to perform inline substitution, so you will have to provide `inline` if the definition of the function is in a header file that is included across different files.

A specialized function template is like an ordinary function because all the template parameters have been fixed (i.e., function templates can't be *partially* specialized). Therefore, if the (fully) specialized function template is in a header file, you should make it `inline` to cope with the One Definition Rule just in the same way you should do it with an ordinary function.

Comment: thanks, I'm interested only about `inline substitution` case, does my example code make any difference with `inline` keyword on non specialized template functions for that case? for example I want to hint the compiler to inline the "expanded" template function in call site.

Comment: I think you will have to look at compile-specific documentation for that. Anyway, if you want inline substitution of a function, keep in mind that **the compiler must have the definition of this function to be inlined at sight at the moment of the call to this function**. Otherwise, how can the compiler perform the inline substitution?

Comment: That's the reason why you usually put the function definition in a header file and use the `inline` specifier: because this header may be included in multiple files so that the ODR can be broken.

Comment: well if the template function is defined in a header then compiler does have a sight of definition right? I didn't mean to define templates in source file and put `inline` in a header. or  not to include header where function is called and expanded.

Comment: @metablaster yes, template functions are `inline` by default. Also `inline` is *automatically* added to a function defined inside the class definition. Therefore, it also applies to member functions of a class.

Comment: yes I know, but my sample defines function outside the classs but inside the same header. in usual cases with normal functions that does not imply `inline`, can we say the same for template member functions, I don't know edit: ah OK, I see your point. so my 2 sample definition make no difference, both are inline?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found something about this, and it looks like `inline` **does** make a difference for template definition in a header, IE. if you omit `inline` then that function is not inline!

[Reference link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl)

**Quote:**

> As an example, consider the header file Foo.h which contains the
>   following template class. **Note that method Foo::f() is inline and
>   methods Foo::g() and Foo::h() are not.**

```
// File "Foo.h"
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  void f();
  void g();
  void h();
};
template<typename T>
inline
void Foo<T>::f()
{
  // ...
}
```

Looks like we can safely conclude that templates are not implicitly inline, but sample implies that other 2 methods are defined in cpp file, so all bets for conclusions are off. still looking for some standard confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

It affects the behavior of **explicit instantiation** declarations (in a fashion meant to encourage actual inlining of inline function templates).  In C++20’s modules, it also affects the ability to use **internal-linkage** (*e.g.*, `static`) entities *from* such a template—again, in a way that’s meant to encourage inlining into importers.  In the latter case, having the definition inside a class **no longer** implies `inline`.