# How can I resolve this one or more multiply defined symbol found error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, template-specialization

What is the bug in the following project?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "template_specialization_conflict_test.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << utils::my_template_function(0.555);
    std::cout<<utils::my_template_function<double>(0.555);
    return 0;
}
```

**template_specialization_conflict_test.hpp**

```
#ifndef UTILS__UTILS__UTILS__UTILS
#define UTILS__UTILS__UTILS__UTILS
#include <iostream>

namespace utils
{
    // A generic function
    template <class T>
    T my_template_function(T parameter)
    {
        std::cout << "function template";
        std::cout << parameter;
        return parameter;
    }

    // Template Specialization
    //      A function specialized for double data type
    template <>
    double my_template_function<double>(double parameter)
    {
        std::cout << "function specialization on double";
        std::cout << parameter;
        return parameter;
    }
}
#endif
```

**template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp**

```
#include "template_specialization_conflict_test.hpp"

namespace utils
{
    //empty
}
```

**Error**

```
>------ Rebuild All started: Project: template_specialization_conflict_test, Configuration: x64-Debug ------
  [1/1] Cleaning all built files...
  Cleaning... 2 files.
  [1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir\main.cpp.obj
  [2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir\template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp.obj
  [3/3] Linking CXX executable template_specialization_conflict_test.exe
  FAILED: template_specialization_conflict_test.exe 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- "C:\PROGRA~2\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" /nologo CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir\template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir\main.cpp.obj  /out:template_specialization_conflict_test.exe /implib:template_specialization_conflict_test.lib /pdb:template_specialization_conflict_test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
  LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir\template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir\main.cpp.obj /out:template_specialization_conflict_test.exe /implib:template_specialization_conflict_test.lib /pdb:template_specialization_conflict_test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\template_specialization_conflict_test.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1169) with the following output:
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\template_specialization_conflict_test\out\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2005: "double __cdecl utils::my_template_function<double>(double)" (??$my_template_function@N@utils@@YANN@Z) already defined in template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp.obj
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\template_specialization_conflict_test\out\build\x64-Debug\template_specialization_conflict_test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Rebuild All failed.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unrelated: `_UTILS_` isn't really allowed. It is reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: Define specializations in a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (source file, essentially).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, doesn't work either. Plz, be kind enough to show me.

Comment: Move `template <> double my_template_function<double>(double parameter)` and its whole body into the `template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp` source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, doesn't work. 

Comment: @user366312 shouldn't main.cpp.obj come 1st in the linker list?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @ChrisMM, please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) It's the leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter that makes it reserved.

Comment: Did you remember to put the specialization in the `utils` namespace in the source file? Did you remember to ***remove*** the specialization from the header file? If I do that I get no error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, then why don't you post an answer?

Comment: All function definitions in header files must be inline, otherwise you risk ODR violations as you have observed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it make any sense to use inline keyword with templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates)

Comment: @Quimby, Okay, but why moving the definition to the source file solve the issue, then?

Comment: @user366312 Because you don't include source files in other source files. The issue is the symbol appearing in multiple Translation Units and the linker does not know what to do. So either you move it into one source file=TU or mark it `inline` so linker does not complain. It is the same as for any other function. Look at [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work).

Comment: I'm a little rusty on templates, but why does the specialization for double have any template syntax at all? Why not just declare `double my_template_function(double parameter);`? And then put the definition in template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp?

Comment: @DS_London, Coz, I am debugging a larger code-base, and they wrote it like this. I have been debugging this code for the last 5 days.

Comment: @DS_London Then it is not a specialization but just a normal function coincidentally named `my_template_function`. Overloading resolution will then have to pick between the template and the function.

Comment: @Quimby The resolution seems to work as I would expect it on my compiler (VS 2019). My hazy recollection is that the compiler only generates templated code if it can't find a match among non-templated functions?

Comment: @DS_London Overload resolution just picks the correct candidate function, generating the code from templates happens after that if a template has been selected.  Yes, non-template functions are preferred but still "the best match" is chosen, that can be a template even if some other candidate exists. Thus between `template<T> foo(T);`,  `template<> foo<int>(int);`, and `foo(int)`.  The last one would be picked for `foo(5)`. So explicit specializations are still penalized from coming from template functions. `foo(5.0)` picks the generic version even though `foo(int)` would compile too.

Comment: @Quimby I don't want to hijack this thread but how is the declaration `template<> foo(int)` resolved? Is this a template specialization or a non-template one? Or indeed `template<> foo<>(int)` which also compiles and runs.

Comment: @DS_London The compiler tries to find the primary template that matches the specialization. `<>` after `foo` is not needed as long all the template arguments can be deduced ( by the same algorithm as the one used for calls to template functions). So `template<> foo(int)` is same as writing `template<> foo<>(int)` and the compiler can deduce `T=int` so you do not have to write `template <> foo<int>(int)`. Had you wrote `template<> foo<int>(double)` you would get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

You could solve this by adding/using the keyword `inline` for the specialization so the specialization would look like:

```
   //note the keyword inline in the below specialization
   template <> inline
    double my_template_function<double>(double parameter)
    {
        std::cout << "function specialization on double";
        std::cout << parameter;
        return parameter;
    }
```

This works as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Oo4ufmwNp).

**Second** way to solve this would be to move your specialization into the source file instead of the header. So your **template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp** would look like:
**template_specialization_conflict_test.cpp**

```
#include "template_specialization_conflict_test.hpp"

namespace utils
{
    // Template Specialization
    //      A function specialized for double data type
    template <> 
    double my_template_function<double>(double parameter)
    {
        std::cout << "function specialization on double";
        std::cout << parameter;
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

The program works as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/8KBsaesla) and [here(with gcc and clang)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LPEskUPpso6qtRSf).

Comment: What are the other ways?

Comment: @user366312 I wrote "one way" because i am taking into account the possibility of other ways(if any).

Comment: This second way doesn't work in my VS2019. I already tried it.

Comment: @user366312 I tried the second method in VS 2019 (both with C++ 14 & 17) and it compiled fine. You need to leave the declaration of the specialization in the header though. The code didn't seem to care whether I included `<double>`, `<>` or neither in the declaration and definition.

Comment: @DS_London Definitely need to leave `<>` `<double>` there, as I explained in my comments under the question. Do not mix overload and template specializations if you can avoid it.

Comment: @Quimby My comment here crossed with yours above. Thanks for the explanation!