# C++ static template class member variable: non-inline external definitions are not permitted in C++ header units

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, inline, c++-modules

I wanted to start a new project that uses modules, and therefore had to put header-only libraries in a header unit. One of them (sol2) triggered an error (the one in the title) when compiling with Clang. I was able to reproduce the error on a smaller header file, and it turns out that the error only occurs when compiling with Clang: GCC doesn't see the issue when compiling the file as a header unit (the code will be below).

Now, ***I know that the header unit support in both compilers is experimental.*** My question is: ***when*** it is finished, ***which*** behavior will be correct? I was under the impression that static template class member variables should be automatically marked inline, but it looks like Clang disagrees? Am I wrong to expect that variable to be considered inline here, or is Clang wrong?

The test header file in question:

```cpp
#pragma once

template <typename T> struct S { static int v; };
template <typename T> int S<T>::v = 10;

template <typename T> bool b() {
    bool b1 = S<T>::v == 10;
    return b1 && true;
}

inline bool B = b<int>();
```

Precompiled into a header unit with

```bash
[clan]g++ -std=c++23 -fmodule-header -xc++-user-header temp.hh
```

GCC emits no errors. Clang emits:

```
./temp.hh:5:33: error: non-inline external definitions are not permitted in C++ header units
5 | template <typename T> int S<T>::v = 10;
  |                                 ^
./temp.hh:8:21: note: in instantiation of static data member 'S<int>::v' requested here
8 |     bool b1 = S<T>::v == 10;
  |                     ^
./temp.hh:12:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'b<int>' requested here
12 | inline bool B = b<int>();
   |                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: "I was under the impression that static template class member variables should be automatically marked inline" There doesn't seem to be such provision in the standard.

Comment: I couldn't find anything either - hence the question. It seems natural, though: there should only exist one instance of a static member variable per template instance, which multiple TUs can trigger and which needs to be provided from a header file, and all usages would be expected to use that same variable across all TUs.

TL;DR in case I wrote an incomprehensible mess of a paragraph: I've checked in GCC and Clang with two TUs and a common header with a class template and a static variable. It compiled, it didn't show ODR violation, it linked and it behaved like an inline variable. :|

Comment: hmm actually they behaved like that before inline variables became a thing.But they don't seen to be considered inline (just like function templates are not considered inline by default).

Comment: So we have these weird variables that behaved like inline variables even before those were introduced (and keep behaving this way) but are not actually considered inline? Or am I missing something here and there is a difference?

Comment: ok this is embarrassing for me :| they are not inline and I was one request away from having an example served to me, except with function templates. Not having the static variable inline CAN cause multiple definition errors when linking. I will be making an answer an marking the question as solved. Thank you for staying here and explaining it to me :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this member variable is not inline. A similar thing happens with function templates, that are **not** implicitly inline either (see [Does it make any sense to use inline keyword with templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates)). A simple modification to a header file reveals a potential multiple definition error:

```cpp
    #pragma once
    
    template <typename T>
    struct S { static int i; };
    
    template <typename T> int S<T>::i = 10;
    template <> int S<int>::i = 10;
```

And yay

```
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLUB00S.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `S<int>::i'; /tmp/ccAQtrFM.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

P.S. I still can't think of a case where this will work with `inline`, though. Sure, the linker error transforms into a compiler `duplicate initialization` error, so how do we use our power now? Either way, the variable is **not** inline here and Clang is right, and GCC apparently is too, because what headers could be imported is apparently implementation defined:

> An importable header is a member of an implementation-defined set of headers that includes all importable C++ library headers (16.5.1.2).

*Splendid!*

Comment: The answer you've linked says that defining a static variable of a full specialization without `inline` can cause ODR violation. However, this doesn't explains the use case in your question (which doesn't do a full specialization (`template <typename T> int S<T>::v = 10;` is not full specialization). Suppose the only explaination is the implementation-defined-ness of header units.

Comment: I guess it was kind of a two-part question :) But yeah, with header units specifically I guess there is just no definite answer at all as to "what is right". Unless I'm misinterpreting the standard. I won't be marking the answer as correct just in case, since I'm not entirely sure I got everything right